# C++: Normal Distribution in Utility Namespace

Tags: c++

I want to create a utility namespace that includes a function that generates numbers following a normal distribution with specified mean and variance.

MathUtils.hpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

namespace MathUtils {
    double genNormalDist();


    extern std::random_device rd;
    extern std::mt19937 gen;
    extern std::normal_distribution<> normalDist;
};
```

MathUtils.cpp

```
MathUtils::gen = rd();

MathUtils::normalDist = std::normal_distribution<double>(
    0, sqrt(2/(inputNumber + outputNumber)));
  \\Error here: Types 'long' and 'normal_distribution' are not compatible

double MathUtils::genNormalDist() {
    return normalDist(gen);
}
```

Other parts of the program will call MathUtils::genNormalDist(). Other parts of the program will not need to access rd, gen, or normalDist. What is the best way to implement this?

Starting to learn C++, much guidance needed. Thanks!

Comment: Don't declare the global variables `extern`. Declare them `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare the variables in the namespace as `extern`. A bit tricky to understand why, I'll try to give it a shot.

What you want is to create a new variable in the namespace. Thus, you need to define the variable (i.e. allocate memory for it) in the namespace. If you declare your variable as `extern`, it would basically be saying "Don't create a *new* variable, i'm just letting you know that this variable exists somewhere so I can use it here".

However, a better approach would be to write a small class.